# open command prompt in hidden mode through java

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt

i want to open command prompt through java and perform some task.
but i want to open that command prompt in hidden mode.

```
command = "cmd.exe /c start doxygen " + strDoxyfilePath; 

Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: What's your question? The code you posted will run that command without opening a command prompt if you remove the cmd.exe.

Comment: @jon7 yes but i want to open command prompt but in hidden mode.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still unclear about your question. Is there a difference between running a command without a command prompt and running a command with a hidden command prompt?

Comment: @jon7 yes actually some time when i run this command without command prompt that time it stuck and if i run this command with command prompt then it work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following command to start your program **minimized**

```
command = "cmd.exe /c start /min doxygen " + strDoxyfilePath; 
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for this, this will do what you want to do in your above code

```
String strDoxyfilePath = "any path";
        String[] Command ={"doxygen",strDoxyfilePath};
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(Command).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Same thing with ProcessBuilder. Also nice solution ;o)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

String YourFilePath="c:\....";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start /min "+YourFilePath);

Comment: Some additional information would probably be useful.